# Inject JS into WKWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

In one of my application, I am migrating the uiwebview to wkwebview.At the time of injecting the JS,it showing the error like below "JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type",but same JS working in uiwebview.And I am injecting the JS in didfinish delegate method.So please let me know how to solve this issue.And My Javascript is

{
NSString* INJECT_JS = @"window.EasyJS={__callbacks: {},invokeCallback:function (cbID, removeAfterExecute){var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);args.shift();args.shift();for (vari = 0, l = args.length; i < l; i++){args[i] = decodeURIComponent(args[i]);}var cb = EasyJS.__callbacks[cbID];if (removeAfterExecute){EasyJS.__callbacks[cbID] = undefined;}return cb.apply(null, args);},call: function (obj, functionName, args){var formattedArgs = [];for (var i = 0, l = args.length; i < l; i++){if (typeof args[i] == \"function\"){formattedArgs.push(\"f\");
var cbID = \"__cb\" + (+new Date);EasyJS.__callbacks[cbID] =args[i];formattedArgs.push(cbID);}else{formattedArgs.push(\"s\");formattedArgs.push(encodeURIComponent(args[i]));}}var argStr = (formattedArgs.length > 0 ? \":\" + encodeURIComponent(formattedArgs.join(\":\")) : \"\");var iframe = document.createElement(\"IFRAME\");iframe.setAttribute(\"src\", \"easy-js:\" + obj + \":\" + encodeURIComponent(functionName) +argStr);document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);iframe = null;
var ret = EasyJS.retValue;EasyJS.retValue = undefined;if (ret){return decodeURIComponent(ret);}},inject: function (obj, methods){window[obj] = {};var jsObj = window[obj];for (var i = 0, l = methods.length; i < l; i++){(function (){var method = methods[i];var jsMethod = method.replace(new RegExp(\":\", \"g\"), \"\");jsObj[jsMethod] = function (){return EasyJS.call(obj, method, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));};})();}}}"; 
}

Comment: can you attach the JS or how you implemented the WKWebView

Comment: This is certainly. not how you do it my friend , Update this in your question with {Code} using the options